# Как отправить get запрос ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

Нужно отправить `get` запрос на url:

```
https://api.nametracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{nickname}
```

Как это сделать?
Указать нужно платформу и никнейм

Answer (score 2):

```
fetch(`https://api.nametracker.com/v1/profile/${platform}/${nickname}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => alert(data))
  .catch(alert => console.log(alert));
```

Comment: А как  вот эти nickname и platform из переменной туда закинуть? Я просто никогда не работал с этим)

Comment: они уже там с посощью шаблонной строки. почитайте https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: Метод решает проблему, но он не универсальный и не абстрактный

Answer (score 2):

Советую вам ознакомиться для начала с [учебным пособием Кантора](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) и еще одну статью из [учебника Кантора](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain) и еще [здесь можно почитать](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) про заголовки, в качестве примера привел доработанный код из его учебника.

```js
var platform = 'Какое-то имя платформы';
var nickname = 'Какой-то ник';
var apiKey = 'какой-то ключ API';
var url = 'https://api.nametracker.com/v1/profile/' + platform + '/' + nickname //никнейм и платформа берутся из переменных, можно вставить и другими способами.

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false); //url используется здесь
xhr.setRequestHeader('ApiKey', apiKey); //строка 'ApiKey' скорее всего должна называться по другому, посмотрите в документации.
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
} else {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,а как APIkey туда вставить?

Comment: Тут все зависит от того, как это написано в документации.

Comment: Дан просто url для get запроса и APIkey и все.

Comment: Нужно передать его как заголовок с запросом.

Comment: Добавил строку добавления заголовка, имя заголовка - первый параметр в скобках, скорее всего там другое название у него, смотрите его в документации, и скорее всего, все это зарабоает

Comment: Это ошибка со стороны сервера? - Failed to load https://api.nametracker.com/v1/profile/pc/nickname: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: Это ошибка в кросс-доменных запросах. Почитайте о них. И вам скорее всего не получится получить данные через ajax. Вам или придется писать сервер, который будет отправлять запрос, или если это ваш API, то на сервере поменять настройки и разрешить кросс-доменные запросы.

Answer (score 1):

```
var platform = 'test';
var nickname = 'test';

$.get('https://api.nametracker.com/v1/profile/' + platform + '/' + nickname, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: А как  вот эти nickname и platform из переменной туда закинуть? Я просто никогда не работал с этим)

Comment: Тут нет подстановки параметров в шаблонную строку

Comment: Если апи принимает параметры в урл. Возможно ли их отправлять в data секции аякса? Пока ловлю 404, но может быть я что делаю не так

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы отправить запрос с нужными параметрами, используй эту функцию, для того, чтобы построить URL с нужными параметрами:

```js
function buildPathWithParams(path, params) {
  if (!params) {
   return path;
  }

  var matches = path.match(/{\w+}/g);

  if (!matches) {
    return path;
  }

  matches.forEach(match => {
    var propName = match.replace(/({|})/g, '');
    path = path.replace(match, params[propName]);
  });

  return path;
}


var result = buildPathWithParams('https://api.nametracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{nickname}', {platform: 'MyPlatform', nickname: 'MyNickname'});

console.log(result);
```

После делаешь обычный GET запрос, для примера оставлю ссылку на пример GET запроса на всякий случай 
https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @IvanZ я тебе советую использовать универсальный способ для подстановки переменных в шаблонную строку.